# How can I remove/edit a document marked Raven-Read-Only?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

A document in our RavenDB database was accidentally deleted, and in an attempt to fix the issue a revision was renamed to the primary document and saved, keeping the MetaData.

```
{
"Raven-Document-Revision-Status": "Historical",
"Raven-Read-Only": "true",
"Raven-Document-Parent-Revision": ".../revisions/57"
}
```

The "Raven-Read-Only" attribute appears to prevent all writing and deleting of this document. Which is problematic for our application. Even from within the Studio there doesn't appear to be a way modify/delete this document. Am I overlooking something there? Or is there another way to modify this data, or at the very least delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by turning off the versioning bundle. Once it was off I was able to delete the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing the metadata items for:

```
"Raven-Document-Revision-Status",
"Raven-Read-Only",
"Raven-Document-Parent-Revision"
```

Removing all three and then saving would allow you to do so.

Comment: I tested this out in one of our test environments. And as long as the versioning bundle was enabled, I was unable to make any changes to the document (including removing those metadata items). Once I disabled the versioning bundle I could remove those three properties. I then re-enabled versioning and everything was good as new.

Comment: just to mention that "to disable the versioning" meant to look at the database in studio and delete the "document" that's called versioning.

Comment: It seems because I have encryption enabled I still cannot edit the database. 
What to do?

Comment: Please post in the mailing list with full details. The encryption bundle doesn't relate to versioning at all